# "I'm three times as more profitable as my salary" vs. "I'm as three times more profitable as my salary"

Tags: comparative-constructions

> I'm three times as more profitable as my salary

vs.

> I'm as three times more profitable as my salary

Comment: Which do you think is better, and why?

Comment: Are you trying to express that you are worth three times as much as you are being paid? Both examples you've given sound a little odd. If you clarify what you're trying to express, it might be easier to help

Comment: I would say "The profit I generate for my company is more than three times my salary" and "The profit I generate for my company is exactly three times my salary". (I'm not sure whether we can say *I am profitable* so I changed the wording)

Comment: A rule of thumb at U.S. defense contractors is that a good engineer needs to provide incremental value to the company equal to three times the engineer's salary.  This is partly because the company must pay for various non-salary benefits, partly because the company must pay for the engineer's office and support services, partly because the company needs to make a profit on its investment, and partly because the engineer's value added occurs in the margin between gross revenues and the operating expenses needed to make things.

Comment: A rule of thumb in macro-economics is that (in the economy overall) wages, salaries, employee benefits, and payroll taxes typically add up to 60% to 70% of gross product.  The remainder goes towards capital depreciation, returns on capital, and taxes.

Comment: @ CowperKettle Why volunteer to answer a question you are not fit to answer as your first language is another one?

Answer (score 4):

I agree with the comments of @Joe Pinsonault and @CowperKettle.

First,
I might phrase the sentence more along the lines of:

> *I am worth three times as much as I am being paid.*

or

> *My annual profit for the company is three times higher than my salary.*

---

Second,
"As" and "More" are never used together in the same phrase in comparative constructions.

You could say,

> *I'm three times more beautiful than she is.*

or

> *I'm three times as beautiful as she is.*

But you cannot say

> *I'm three times **as** **more** beautiful as she is.*

And you cannot say

> *I'm **as** three times **more** beautiful as she is.*

So the general rule is

either use

**AS-AS**

subject + verb + (optional modifier) + **AS** + adjective + **AS** + comparison-noun

*example: His house is three times AS big AS mine.*

*example: Engineering can be AS confusing AS philosophy.*

or use

**MORE-THAN**

subject + verb + (optional modifier) + **MORE** + adjective + **THAN** + comparison-noun

*example: Mary was MORE excited THAN me to receive an invitation.*

*example: Swimming is MORE relaxing THAN boxing.*

but never use AS-MORE together

Answer (score 3):

In addition to what Peter said, I don't think that the general construction of the sentences is correct

For example, with

> I'm three times as more profitable as my salary

Generally this kind of comparison (more than, less than) is of the form

> I'm three times **more** profitable **than** my salary

or

> I'm three times **as** profitable **as** my salary

In your sentences you've mixed the two constructions together

[This](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/comparatives-and-superlatives/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting) might help if you want more details about how to construct comparisons

Answer (score 0):

The comparison between your profitability and your salary would be

> I'm three times as profitable as my salary.

"more" is redundant since three times is already "more".

> I'm as three times more profitable as my salary.

would be comparing yourself to your profitability, when you really want to compare your salary.

Comment: I would just add that we don't usually use the word "profitable" to refer to people. A business can be profitable, or an investment can be profitable, or a situation can be profitable. We usually talk about people as being "worth" something though. As in "I'm worth more than my boss but they get paid more than me"

Comment: It's a normal form of shorthand if an individual or group is closely identified with an activity or Profit & Loss account, especially in sales functions, a usual question might be "Is he profitable?" when what is meant is "Are his sales activities profitable?".  One could ask about a company "Are they profitable?" which would not refer to the individuals in the company *pre se* but the aggregate activities of the company.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that sales lingo!

Comment: How can a salary be profitable? Can it make money?

Comment: He's not saying his salary is profitable, he's saying the profit he makes is more than his salary. He could have said "I'm three time more profitable than my salary" meaning I bring in three times more money than I cost (not including overhead) the company.